# how to insert different shipping cost in prestashop carrier module development

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

in my controller, i have cost value for shipping.i'm trying to send it to `getOrderShippingCost` function. but my cart showing shipping `free`

**Controller.php**

```
$cost_val=120; //this value can be change

include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'delivery_scheduler/delivery_scheduler.php');

    $DeliveryWeekSched=new delivery_scheduler();

    $DeliveryWeekSched->getOrderShippingCost($cost_val,$cost_val);
```

**delivery_scheduler.php**

```
public function getOrderShippingCost($params, $shipping_cost)
    {
        if (Context::getContext()->customer->logged == true)
        {
            $id_address_delivery = Context::getContext()->cart->id_address_delivery;
            $address = new Address($id_address_delivery);
            return 100; // i want to return `$shipping_cost`
        }
        return $shipping_cost;
    }
```

when return `$shipping_cost` shipping value in cart showing `free`.when `100` return cart shipping value showing `100`.why is that?how to return my value?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by setting your carrier additional fees such as taxes and handling_rates to zero then set is as "not free"